# How to post an Ajax onClick through a looping input form (Dinamically) from MySql query result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I would like to be suggested on how to solve an Ajax post through a looping input form (Dynamically) from MySql query result.

```
<?php
// Query Result
foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {
echo '
<div class="media mt-4">
  <div class="media-body text-muted text-small">
    <input class="d-none" value="'.$row->cY.'" name="post_X" id="post_X">
    <input class="d-none" value="'.$row->cZ.'" name="post_Y" id="post_Y">
    <div class="input-group">                             
      <input style="background:#fafafa" type="text" name="post_Z" id="post_Z" placeholder="Join conversation here..." class="form-control">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" onclick="addPost()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
}
?>
```

Ajax script

```
<script>
function addPost() {
    if(!$("#post_Z").val()) {
        // An Alert!
    } else {
        var post_X = $("#post_X").val();
        var post_Y = $("#post_Y").val();
        var post_Z = $("#post_Z").val();
        $.post("reply.php", {
            uid: post_X,
            cid: post_Y,
            txt: post_Z
        }, function (data, status) {
            // An Alert!
        });
    };
}
</script>
```

Thanks alot

Comment: id's need to be unique, see html standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: One problem I see is that you are (potentially) creating multiple inputs with the same value for `id`. All id's should be unique. Names can be the same, and are returned as an array on submit. Anyway, your statements like `var post_X = $("#post_X").val();` are indeterminate since they refer to multiple input objects.

Comment: how to modify the Ajax if i gave them unique IDs to the three inputs by using variable $x=1, $x++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give an id for each iteration, and add the id in the addPost event so that the post only retrieves data according to the id that is defined

change the code to be like this

```
<?php
// Query Result

$uniq = 1;
foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {
echo '
<div class="media mt-4">
  <div class="media-body text-muted text-small">
    <input class="d-none" value="'.$row->cY.'" name="post_X_'.$uniq.'" id="post_X_'.$uniq.'">
    <input class="d-none" value="'.$row->cZ.'" name="post_Y_'.$uniq.'" id="post_Y_'.$uniq.'">
    <div class="input-group">                             
      <input style="background:#fafafa" type="text" name="post_Z_'.$uniq.'" id="post_Z_'.$uniq.'" placeholder="Join conversation here..." class="form-control">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" onclick="addPost('.$uniq.')" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
$uniq++;
}
?>
```

and the ajax

```
<script>
function addPost(id) {
    if(!$("#post_Z_"+id).val()) {
        // An Alert!
    } else {
        var post_X = $("#post_X_"+id).val();
        var post_Y = $("#post_Y_"+id).val();
        var post_Z = $("#post_Z_"+id).val();
        $.post("reply.php", {
            uid: post_X,
            cid: post_Y,
            txt: post_Z
        }, function (data, status) {
            // An Alert!
        });
    };
}
</script>
```

may these help